# Eclipse import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.* Error

Tags: eclipse, annotations

I want to build customized annotation class in eclipse, however, it could import static RetentionPolicy enum, *CANNOT* import *ElementType*.

```
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.*;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;
```

The error message is

> The type java.lang.annotation.ElementType cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required type java.lang.annotation.Target

How should I setup the configuration in eclipse because these codes can be built in command and IntelliJ

Comment: It looks like your project is not correctly configured. What Java version do you use in your project (in the _Package Explorer_ or _Project Explorer_, what _JRE System Library_ is shown? `JavaSE-?`)?

Comment: JavaSE is 21, and it exists in Build Path.

Comment: well, i deleted the .metadata folder and re-maven import all projects, it works.

Comment: Never ever delete the `.metadata` folder since this can cause damage (e.g. you can wreck your workspace and lose data with that). Simply try a new workspace instead.